# mongodb ObjectId find with sails, returns all the data

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo

in my sails controller I have implement a function to find users. but when I try to search using ObjectId it returns all the data. I couldn't find any reason. but it works when I create a new separate field as "userID", and find using "userID". I think the problem is find using the "ObjectId" what could be the issue.

```
module.exports = {

    updateOrders : function(req,res){

    var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
    console.log("req " + req);
    var data = req.body;
    var obj = [];


console.log("\ndata "+(data));

var jdata = JSON.stringify(data);
console.log("\njdata: "+jdata);

    data.forEach(function(orders){

        var objid = ObjectId(orders.id);
        console.log("Obj orders id  :" + objid);


        ApplicationOrder.find({id: ObjectId(orders.id)}).exec(function (err, order) {

            if (err){
                return done(err);
            }

            console.log('order ' + order);
             obj.push(order);
        });


    })
        res.send(obj);




        }


};
```

Json data: printed in the console.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59a8f820caf1cae37af72c0c"),
    "appId" : "59a669431954a69e37c20b69",
    "registeredUser" : "59a677811954a69e37c20b73",
    "item" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "59a669441954a69e37c20b70",
            "name" : "Short x",
            "qty" : 1,
            "sku" : "1111",
            "totWeight" : null,
            "price" : "250",
            "total" : "250",
            "imgURL" : [ 
                {
                    "img" : "short_x.png"
                }
            ],
            "totalQty" : 218
        }
    ],
    "amount" : "250",
    "customerName" : "dilakshan",
    "deliverName" : "dilakshan",
    "deliveryNo" : "11010",
    "deliveryStreet" : "delgoda",
    "deliveryCity" : "kandana",
    "deliveryCountry" : "Sri Lanka",
    "deliveryZip" : "11010",
    "telNumber" : 94779967409,
    "tax" : "0",
    "shippingCost" : "0",
    "shippingOpt" : "Flat Rate",
    "email" : "s.dilakshan@yahoo.com",
    "currency" : "$",
    "paymentStatus" : "Pending",
    "fulfillmentStatus" : "Pending",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-09-01T06:03:12.584Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-09-01T06:03:12.584Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59a8f82fcaf1cae37af72c0d"),
    "appId" : "59a669431954a69e37c20b69",
    "registeredUser" : "59a677811954a69e37c20b73",
    "item" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "59a669441954a69e37c20b6d",
            "name" : "Shirt x",
            "qty" : 1,
            "sku" : "1111",
            "totWeight" : null,
            "price" : "250",
            "total" : "250",
            "imgURL" : [ 
                {
                    "img" : "shirt_x.png"
                }
            ],
            "totalQty" : 244
        }
    ],
    "amount" : "250",
    "customerName" : "dilakshan",
    "deliverName" : "dilakshan",
    "deliveryNo" : "11010",
    "deliveryStreet" : "delgoda",
    "deliveryCity" : "kandana",
    "deliveryCountry" : "Sri Lanka",
    "deliveryZip" : "11010",
    "telNumber" : 94779967409,
    "tax" : "0",
    "shippingCost" : "0",
    "shippingOpt" : "Flat Rate",
    "email" : "s.dilakshan@yahoo.com",
    "currency" : "$",
    "paymentStatus" : "Pending",
    "fulfillmentStatus" : "Pending",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-09-01T06:03:27.022Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-09-01T06:03:27.022Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59a8f83ecaf1cae37af72c0e"),
    "appId" : "59a669431954a69e37c20b69",
    "registeredUser" : "59a677811954a69e37c20b73",
    "item" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "59a669441954a69e37c20b71",
            "name" : "Beach Suit",
            "qty" : 2,
            "sku" : "1111",
            "totWeight" : null,
            "price" : "250",
            "total" : "250",
            "imgURL" : [ 
                {
                    "img" : "cloth3.png"
                }
            ],
            "totalQty" : 238
        }
    ],
    "amount" : "500",
    "customerName" : "dilakshan",
    "deliverName" : "dilakshan",
    "deliveryNo" : "11010",
    "deliveryStreet" : "delgoda",
    "deliveryCity" : "kandana",
    "deliveryCountry" : "Sri Lanka",
    "deliveryZip" : "11010",
    "telNumber" : 94779967409,
    "tax" : "0",
    "shippingCost" : "0",
    "shippingOpt" : "Flat Rate",
    "email" : "s.dilakshan@yahoo.com",
    "currency" : "$",
    "paymentStatus" : "Pending",
    "fulfillmentStatus" : "Pending",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-09-01T06:03:42.439Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-09-01T06:03:42.439Z")
}
```

Comment: Can you please be more clear about what your code does and what you are expecting it to do? You mention that the controller action should "find users" and I see the a `registeredUser` ID is returned with each ApplicationOrder row queried. Is the desired behavior different than this?

Comment: **registeredUser** ID is for a particular user who logged in. it will differ from user to user when they signup. in this criteria its for a selected products also having a unique **id**. the problem is when I use the ObjectId to find the particular data it returns all the other data.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Have you tried specifying `_id` like this: `ApplicationOrder.find({&#39;_id&#39;: orders. Id})...`? Also remember that `.find` returns (thru the callback)  results as an array, so `order` in your code would really be `orders`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to fix the issue. I had to edit the my model class in sails and use only **orders.id** model class,

`_id:{type : 'objectid'}`   and when **search**

`.find({_id: orders.id})`

this worked for me perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

For standard sails.js/waterline queries, you have to use the id as a String in your query params, do not use `ObjectId(ordersId)`.

When you use a sails native query, use `ObjectId(ordersId)`.

Comment: I have tried that it returns no result for me. but I was able to print my parsed "order.id" value. when I use` {id:orders.id}` it gives me no data. It only returns some data when I use only  **ObjectId**. but it returns all the other datas.

Comment: I guess orders is an array, is it? You need to retrieve it properly so that the id is a String or and array of Strings.

Comment: yes _order_ is an array. the thing is **.find** criteria returns all the objects in my mongodb database. it's not returning the object that I specified with the ObjectId. thts what I have printed in the console as **returned Objects** in my function.

Comment: Use findById(orders.id) method once

Comment: If orders is an array of objects, then of course orders.id does not work. You need to retrieve id one by one from each object and put it in a new array. I am using lodash: let orderIds = _.map(orders, 'id');

Comment: I am sure doing `orders.id` is the error. An array does not have a key `id`, only an object could have one. So get all the ids like explained in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using any mongodb adapter then do not try to convert id by ObjectId(orders.id).Try normal query like

```
 ApplicationOrder.find({'id':orders.id})
```

For native sails query,you have to convert id to objectId.

Comment: I have tried that it returns no result for me. but I was able to print my parsed "order.id" value. when I use` {id:orders.id}` it gives me no data. It only returns some data when I use only  **ObjectId**. but it returns all the other datas. Also I have found something. when I delete the 'id' data field from the parsed JSON data it still returns me all the objects.

Comment: `ApplicationOrder.native(function(err, collection) {
                if (err) return res.serverError(err);

                collection.find({'_id':ObjectId(orders.id)}).toArray(function (err, results) {
                    if (err) return res.serverError(err);
                    console.log(results);
                    return res.ok(results);
                });
            })`              **this code returns me**   _TypeError: Argument must be a string
_

Comment: Use findById(orders.id) method once